# Change URL of Web Application on a remote Glassfish Server

Tags: java, dns, glassfish

Actually, I have deployed a web application on a remote server and I can access it by this url: `bt1svw38:7071/rcu/Login` via local machine.

I'm asked to change the url to something like this: `rcu.dopr.windows1:7071/rcu/Login`.

The remote server IP is configured on DNS to have the alias: `rcu.dopr.windows1`.

So, if I try to replace `bt1svw38:7071/rcu/Login` by {ServeripAdress}: `7071/rcu/Login`, everything works fine.

Then if I ping `rcu.dopr.windows1`, I get the response from the {ServeripAdress}
so, the DNS Configuration is fine.

But, If I try to access the application via: `rcu.dopr.windows1:7071/rcu/Login`, I get:

> Network Access Message: The website cannot be found Explanation: 
>   The IP   address for the website you requested could not be found.
>   Error Code 11001: Host not found
>   Background:This error indicates that the gateway could not find the IP address of the website you are trying to access. This is usually due to a DNS-related error.

So, I would like to ask you how to configure the url of web application deployed on `GlassFish` on a remote server so that I can access it on a local machine.

Comment: I would contact the network admin and ask them to check the DNS configuration in the network of the remote server

Comment: Also ensure there isn't a proxy redirecting the request to another DNS